# what is the best way to manage and store Oauth2 token in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot application that communicates with an external rest API that uses Oauth2  and returns a token and refresh token valid for 90 days. 
My question is what is the best way to manage and store these tokens or atleast store the refresh token (i'm currently thinking of storing them in the database).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store your token is in a distributed cache like redis, or in the database but never in session or memory of the server that run your application, you will lose the scalability of your application

Comment: thank you for replying , thats what i was considering to do